# What is the meaning of the word logits in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, cross-entropy

In the following TensorFlow function, we must feed the activation of artificial neurons in the final layer. That I understand. But I don't understand why it is called logits? Isn't that a mathematical function?

```
loss_function = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
     logits = last_layer,
     labels = target_output
)
```

Comment: see this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/what-does-the-logit-value-actually-mean/498922#498922

Comment: comment edited; i'm still learning abou tthis.  surprised nobody is mentioning log-odds from logistic regression.  the term is shortened to 'logits' in wikipedia, and is the mathematical input to the statistical softmax function that ends neural networks.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Logistic_model

Answer (score 415):

Logits is an overloaded term which can mean many different things:

---

**In Math**, [Logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) is a function that maps probabilities (`[0, 1]`) to R (`(-inf, inf)`)

[image]

Probability of 0.5 corresponds to a logit of 0. Negative logit correspond to probabilities less than 0.5, positive to > 0.5.

**In ML**, it [can be](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/glossary/#logits)

> the vector of raw (non-normalized) predictions that a classification
>   model generates, which is ordinarily then passed to a normalization
>   function. If the model is solving a multi-class classification
>   problem, logits typically become an input to the softmax function. The
>   softmax function then generates a vector of (normalized) probabilities
>   with one value for each possible class.

**Logits also** [sometimes](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/glossary/#logits) refer to the element-wise inverse of the sigmoid function.

Comment: For Tensorflow: It's a name that it is thought to imply that this Tensor is the quantity that is being mapped to probabilities by the Softmax.

Comment: is this just the same as the thing that gets exponentiated before the softmax? i.e. `softmax(logit) = exp(logit)/Z(logit)` then `logit = h_NN(x)`? so logit is the same as "score"?

Comment: Personal understanding, in TensorFlow domain, logits are the values to be used as input to softmax. I came to this understanding based on this tensorflow tutorial.

Comment: I am not sure whether this answers the question. Maybe that is why it was never accepted. I understand what the logit function is, but it also puzzles my why Tensorflow calls these arguments logits. It is also the same designation for several of the parameters in Tensorflow's functions

Comment: Greate!Can you make a simple example?  Is this right?`[1, 0.5, 0.5]` through normalization become `[0.5, 0.25, 0.25]` and then soft max become`[0,]` if one hot `[1, 0, 0]`? or just out put `[1, 0, 0]` cause the output should be a vector?

Comment: In TensorFlow, logit refers to the unscaled output of a layer, which can be input into **any** activation function, not just Softmax. This is illustrated by `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`.   The `with_logits` suffix simply denotes that unscaled logit output should be passed, not the prediction output from the final layer activation function that is typically used by error functions such as `tf.keras.losses.MSE` or `tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy`

Comment: Example: the last layer of a NN returns a tensor k = [**1,2,3,4,1,2,3**] of **logits**, which classifies an input as belonging to each of 7 possible categories. Note that the fourth logit is the biggest, i.e., the fourth category is the most probable, and that it is four times the first one. k is fed to a softmax function that returns the probabilities [0.02,0.06, 0.18,0.48,0.02,0.06,0.18] that the input belongs to each category (softmax is a normalized exponential function). Note that the fourth probability is 24 times the first one (due to the exponential term in softmax) and that all sum 1.

Answer (score 219):

Just adding this clarification so that anyone who scrolls down this much can at least gets it right, since there are so many wrong answers upvoted.

Diansheng's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47010867/4334743) and JakeJ's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47278567/4334743) get it right.
[A new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52111173/4334743) posted by Shital Shah is an even better and more complete answer.

---

Yes, `logit`  as a mathematical [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) in statistics, **but the `logit` used in context of neural networks is different.** Statistical `logit` doesn't even make any sense here.

---

I couldn't find a formal definition anywhere, but `logit` basically means:

> The raw predictions which come out of the last layer of the neural network.
>   1. This is the very tensor on which you apply the [`argmax`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max) function to get the predicted class.
>   2. This is the very tensor which you feed into the [`softmax`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) function to get the probabilities for the predicted classes.

---

Also, from a [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers) on official tensorflow website:

> #### Logits Layer
>
> The final layer in our neural network is the logits layer, which will return the raw values for our predictions. We create a dense layer with 10 neurons (one for each target class 0–9), with linear activation (the default):
>
> ```
> logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=10)
> ```

---

If you are still confused, the situation is like this:

```
raw_predictions = neural_net(input_layer)
predicted_class_index_by_raw = argmax(raw_predictions)
probabilities = softmax(raw_predictions)
predicted_class_index_by_prob = argmax(probabilities)
```

where, `predicted_class_index_by_raw` and `predicted_class_index_by_prob` will be equal.

**Another name for `raw_predictions` in the above code is `logit`**.

---

<del>As for the **why** `logit`... I have no idea. Sorry.</del>
[Edit: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52111173/4334743) for  the historical motivations behind the term.]

---

### Trivia

Although, if you want to, you can apply statistical `logit` to `probabilities` that come out of the `softmax` function.

If the probability of a certain class is `p`,
Then the **log-odds** of that class is `L = logit(p)`.

Also, the probability of that class can be recovered as `p = sigmoid(L)`, using the [`sigmoid`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) function.

Not very useful to calculate log-odds though.

Answer (score 156):

**Summary**

In context of deep learning the [logits layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/cnn#logits_layer) means the layer that feeds in to softmax (or other such normalization). The output of the softmax are the probabilities for the classification task and its input is logits layer. The logits layer typically produces values from -infinity to +infinity and the softmax layer transforms it to values from 0 to 1.

**Historical Context**

Where does this term comes from? In 1930s and 40s, several people were trying to adapt linear regression to the problem of predicting probabilities. However linear regression produces output from -infinity to +infinity while for probabilities our desired output is 0 to 1. One way to do this is by somehow mapping the probabilities 0 to 1 to -infinity to +infinity and then use linear regression as usual. One such mapping is cumulative normal distribution that was used by Chester Ittner Bliss in 1934 and he called this "probit" model, short for "probability unit". However this function is computationally expensive while lacking some of the desirable properties for multi-class classification. In 1944 Joseph Berkson used the function `log(p/(1-p))` to do this mapping and called it logit, short for "logistic unit". The term logistic regression derived from this as well.

**The Confusion**

Unfortunately the term logits is abused in deep learning. From pure mathematical perspective logit is a *function* that performs above mapping. In deep learning people started calling the layer "logits layer" that feeds in to logit function. Then people started calling the output *values* of this layer "logit" creating the confusion with logit *the function*.

**TensorFlow Code**

Unfortunately TensorFlow code further adds in to confusion by names like `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`. What does logits mean here? It just means the input of the function is supposed to be the output of last neuron layer as described above. The `_with_logits` suffix is [redundant, confusing and pointless](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6531). Functions should be named without regards to such very specific contexts because they are simply mathematical operations that can be performed on values derived from many other domains. In fact TensorFlow has another similar function `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy` where they fortunately forgot to add `_with_logits` suffix creating inconsistency and adding in to confusion. PyTorch on the other hand simply names its function without these kind of suffixes.

**Reference**

The [Logit/Probit lecture slides](http://www.columbia.edu/~so33/SusDev/Lecture_9.pdf) is one of the best resource to understand logit. I have also updated [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) with some of above information.

Comment: `"From pure mathematical perspective logit is a function that performs above mapping."` This section is wrong. It's common in statistics to call the logit of a probability itself the "logits". `that feeds in to logit function` the SoftMax function isn't the logit function, but its inverse, the (multinomial) **logistic** function.

Answer (score 88):

**Logit** is a function that maps probabilities `[0, 1]` to `[-inf, +inf]`.

**Softmax** is a function that maps `[-inf, +inf]` to `[0, 1]` similar as Sigmoid. But Softmax also normalizes the sum of the values(output vector) to be 1.

**Tensorflow "with logit"**: It means that you are applying a softmax function to logit numbers to normalize it. The input_vector/logit is not normalized and can scale from [-inf, inf].

This normalization is used for multiclass classification problems. And for multilabel classification problems sigmoid normalization is used i.e. `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`

Comment: so logit is the same as the "score"

Comment: I suggest adding a line in your answer explicitly differentiating `Logit` function (statistics) and `logits` layer (tensorflow)

Answer (score 43):

Personal understanding, in TensorFlow domain, logits are the values to be used as input to softmax. I came to this understanding based on this tensorflow tutorial.

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers

---

Although it is true that logit is a function in maths(especially in statistics), I don't think that's the same 'logit' you are looking at. In the book *Deep Learning* by Ian Goodfellow, he mentioned,

> The function σ<sup>−1</sup>(x) is called the logit in statistics, but this term
>   is more rarely used in machine learning. σ<sup>−1</sup>(x) stands for the
>   inverse function of logistic sigmoid function.

In TensorFlow, it is frequently seen as the name of last layer. In Chapter 10 of the book *Hands-on Machine Learning with Scikit-learn and TensorFLow* by Aurélien Géron, I came across this paragraph, which stated `logits` layer clearly.

> note that `logits` is the output of the neural network *before* going
>   through the softmax activation function: for optimization reasons, we
>   will handle the softmax computation later.

That is to say, although we use softmax as the activation function in the last layer in our design, for ease of computation, we take out `logits` separately. This is because it is more efficient to calculate `softmax` and `cross-entropy` loss together. Remember that `cross-entropy` is a cost function, not used in forward propagation.

Answer (score 33):

([FOMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear_of_missing_out)sapiens).

If you check math Logit function, it converts real space from `[0,1]` interval to infinity `[-inf, inf]`.

Sigmoid and softmax will do exactly the opposite thing. They will convert the `[-inf, inf]` real space to `[0, 1]` real space.

This is why, in machine learning we may use logit before sigmoid and softmax function (since they match).

And this is why "we may call" *anything* in machine learning that goes in front of **sigmoid** or **softmax** function the **logit**.

Here is G. Hinton [video](https://youtu.be/mlaLLQofmR8?t=142) using this term.

Answer (score 26):

Here is a concise answer for future readers. Tensorflow's `logit` is defined as the output of a neuron without applying activation function:

```
logit = w*x + b,
```

x: input, w: weight, b: bias. That's it.

---

**The following is irrelevant to this question.**

For historical lectures, read other answers. Hats off to Tensorflow's "creatively" confusing naming convention. In PyTorch, there is only one `CrossEntropyLoss` and it accepts un-activated outputs. Convolutions, matrix multiplications and activations are same level operations. The design is much more modular and less confusing. This is one of the reasons why I switched from Tensorflow to PyTorch.

Comment: This might be correct but completely misses any reference/source of the information.

Answer (score 17):

## logits

The vector of raw (non-normalized) predictions that a classification model generates, which is ordinarily then passed to a normalization function. If the model is solving a multi-class classification problem, logits typically become an input to the softmax function. The softmax function then generates a vector of (normalized) probabilities with one value for each possible class.

In addition, logits sometimes refer to the element-wise inverse of the sigmoid function. For more information, see tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits.

[official tensorflow documentation](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/glossary#logits)

Answer (score 7):

They are basically the fullest learned model you can get from the network, before it's been squashed down to apply to only the number of classes we are interested in.  Check out how some researchers use them to train a shallow neural net based on what a deep network has learned:  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6184.pdf

It's kind of like how when learning a subject in detail, you will learn a great many minor points, but then when teaching a student, you will try to compress it to the simplest case.  If the student now tried to teach, it'd be quite difficult, but would be able to describe it just well enough to use the language.

Answer (score 1):

> The logit (/ˈloʊdʒɪt/ LOH-jit) function is the inverse of the sigmoidal "logistic" function or logistic transform used in mathematics, especially in statistics. When the function's variable represents a probability p, the logit function gives the log-odds, or the logarithm of the odds p/(1 − p).

See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit

Comment: That's in statistics/maths. We are talking machine learning here, where `logit` has different meaning. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47010867/4334743), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50511692/4334743), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47278567/4334743).