# How to get both logits and probabilities from a custom neural network model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

The following source code could get both probabilities and logits from an imagenet pretrained model in Tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim
import tensorflow.contrib.slim.nets as nets
import PIL
import numpy as np

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

#Sets the threshold for what messages will be logged
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
#Starts the Interactive Session
sess=tf.InteractiveSession()

#Get logits and probs from the model
def inception(image, reuse):
    preprocessed = tf.multiply(tf.subtract(tf.expand_dims(image, 0), 0.5), 2.0)
    arg_scope = nets.inception.inception_v3_arg_scope(weight_decay=0.0)
    with slim.arg_scope(arg_scope):
        logits, _ = nets.inception.inception_v3(preprocessed, 1001, is_training=False, reuse=reuse)
        logits = logits[:,1:]
        probs = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    return logits, probs

#Returns logits and probabilities from the network 
logits, probs = inception(image, reuse=False)
```

Now, suppose I have the following model: a RESNET-50 fine tuned in another dataset that I will simply load its model definition and weights:

```
json_file = open('/path/resnet-model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()

model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
#load weights into new model
model.load_weights("/path/weights/resnet-weights.h5")
```

How to make a similar function to take the probs and logits from such an existing pre-trained model?

P.s1: the model, its weights, and an example image input can be found [HERE](https://www3.diism.unisi.it/%7Eferreira/doubts/)

P.s2: some existing solutions to questions like [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56587630/how-do-i-change-the-last-layer-in-keras-to-get-logits-rather-than-probabilities) only explain how to get one or another. I need a function like the first one above that will give me both the logits and probs from an existing trained model loaded from a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you should be able to do this directly the same way:

```
import tensorflow as tf

json_file = open('/content/resnet-model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()

loaded_model_json = loaded_model_json.replace('"activation":"softmax"', '"activation":"linear"')
model = tf.keras.models.model_from_json(loaded_model_json)

image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img('/content/sample-image.jpeg')
image = tf.constant([tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)])
logits = model(image)
probs = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
```

You could also define a new model with the [reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64663867/how-to-create-a-layer-to-invert-a-softmax-tensforflow-python) of a `softmax` function:

```
def inv_softmax(x, C):
   return tf.math.log(x) + C

outputs = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x : inv_softmax(x, tf.math.log(10.)),name='inv_softmax')(model.output)
new_model = tf.keras.Model(model.input, outputs) 
logits = new_model(image)
probs = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
```

Or just drop the last layer and define a new one with a `linear` activation function.