# why explain logit as 'unscaled log probabililty' in sotfmax_cross_entropy_with_logits?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, probability-theory

In the tensorflow documentation ([softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits)), they said "logits : unscaled log probablilty". What is 'log probability'?
First, I understand that `'logits'` is an `'output before normalization'` or a `'score for class'`.

```py
logits = tf.matmul(X,W) + b
hypothesis = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
```

If I got `[1.5, 2.4, 0,7]` by `tf.matmul(X,W) + b`, then `[1.5, 2.4, 0,7]` is `logits(score)` and this was unscaled. I can understand it up to this stage. But, I can't understand why `[1.5, 2.4, 0.7]` is `'log probability'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of the word logits in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41455101/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-word-logits-in-tensorflow)

Comment: Thanks everyone!

I found this post. It solved my question almost.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/what-does-the-logit-value-actually-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone!

I found this post. It solved my question almost.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/what-does-the-logit-value-actually-mean

Answer (score 3):

If you interpret the output of the softmax function as probabilities (as we like to do), then it is easy to see were the "log probability" comes from:

The softmax function is

\exp{z_k}/\sum_i{\exp{z_i}},

with z_i as the components of your "logits". The denominator just takes care of normalization, i.e. it makes sure that all the outputs sum up to 1 (which makes sense if we want to interpret them as probabilities for a set of mutually exclusive classes). So, looking at the numerator, the output of the softmax function is basically just exp(z). If we interpret this as probability, then z (the "logits") is the logarithm of the un-normalized probability.

Comment: It should be obvious that Tex formatting is not supported here. Please format your equations accordingly using the available options.

Comment: What options are there? Feel free to edit if you know of a better way!