# How To specify model.compile for binary_crossentropy, activation=sigmoid and activation=softmax?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, activation-function

I am trying to figure out how to match `activation=sigmoid` and `activation=softmax` with the correct `model.compile(`) loss parameters.  Specifically those associated with `binary_crossentropy`.

I have researched related topics and read the docs.  Also I have built a model and got it working with `sigmoid` but not `softmax`.  And I cannot get it working properly with the "`from_logits`" parameters.

Specifically, [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy) it says:

> Args:
>
> - **`from_logits`**: Whether `output` is expected to be a logits tensor. 
>     By default, we consider that `output` encodes a probability distribution.

This says to me that if you use a `sigmoid` activation you want "`from_logits=True`".  And for `softmax` activation you want "`from_logits=False`" by default.  Here I am assuming that `sigmoid` provides `logits` and `softmax` provides a probability distribution.

Next is some code:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=128,
               input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features), 
               return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(units=32))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Notice the last line is using the `sigmoid` activation.  Then:

```py
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss='binary_crossentropy',  
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This works fine but it is working with the default "from_logits=False" which is expecting a probability distribution.

If I do the following, it fails:

```py
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss='binary_crossentropy',  
              metrics=['accuracy'],
              from_logits=True) # For 'sigmoid' in above Dense
```

with this error message:

> ValueError: Invalid argument "from_logits" passed to K.function with TensorFlow backend

If I try using the softmax activation as:

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
```

It runs but I get 50% accuracy results.  With `sigmoid` I am getting +99% accuracy.  (I am using a very contrived data set to debug my models and would expect very high accuracy.  Plus it is a very small data set and will over fit but that is OK for now.)

So I expect that I should be able to use the "`from_logits`" parameter in the compile function.  But it does not recognize that parameter.

Also I would like to know why it works with the `sigmoid` activation and not the `softmax` activation and how do I get it working with the `softmax` activation.

Thank you,

Jon.

Comment: What is your `keras.__version__`, `tf.__version__`? The docs that you're citing is for  `tf.__version__=='1.13.1'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use the `from_logits` in your loss function, you must pass it into the [BinaryCrossentropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy) object initialization, not in the model compile.

You must change this:

```
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss='binary_crossentropy',  
              metrics=['accuracy'],
              from_logits=True)
```

to this:

```
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),  
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

However, if you are using a softmax or sigmoid in the final layer in the network, you do **not** need `from_logits=True`. Softmax and sigmoid output normalized values between [0, 1], which are considered probabilities in this context.

See this question for more information: [What is the meaning of the word logits in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41455101/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-word-logits-in-tensorflow)

---

Now to fix your 50% accuracy issue with softmax, change the following code from this:

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
```

to this:

```
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))  # number of units = number of classes
```

Remember that when you are using softmax, you are outputting the probability of the example belonging to each class. For this reason, you need a unit for each possible class, which in a binary classification context will be 2 units.

Comment: this answer saved me big time , thanks man you the best!!