# tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy returning wrong value

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have

`y_true = 16`

and

```
y_pred = array([1.1868494e-08, 1.8747659e-09, 1.2777099e-11, 3.6140797e-08,
                6.5852622e-11, 2.2888577e-10, 1.4515833e-09, 2.8392664e-09,
                4.7054605e-10, 9.5605066e-11, 9.3647139e-13, 2.6149302e-10,
                2.5338919e-14, 4.8815413e-10, 3.9381631e-14, 2.1434269e-06,
                9.9999785e-01, 3.0857247e-08, 1.3536775e-09, 4.6811921e-10,
                3.0638234e-10, 2.0818169e-09, 2.9950772e-10, 1.0457132e-10,
                3.2959850e-11, 3.4232595e-10, 5.1689473e-12], dtype=float32)
```

When I use `tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(to_categorical(y_true,num_classes=27),y_pred,from_logits=True)`

The loss value I get is `2.3575358`.

But if I use the formula for categorical cross entropy to get the loss value

```
-np.sum(to_categorical(gtp_out_true[0],num_classes=27)*np.log(gtp_pred[0]))
```

according to the formula [image]

I get the value `2.1457695e-06`

Now, my question is, why does the function `tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy` give different value.

The strange thing is that, my model gives 100% accuracy even though the loss is stuck at 2.3575.
Below is the image of the plot of accuracy and losses during training.

[image]

What formula does Tensorflow use to calculate categorical cross-entropy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y_pred` as a probability vector so you should not use `from_logits=True`. Set it to `False` and you get:

```
>>> print(categorical_crossentropy(to_categorical(16, num_classes = 27),
                                   y_pred, from_logits = False).numpy())
2.264979e-06
```

The reason it is not equal to the expected 2.1457695e-06 is, I belive, because y_pred[16] is very close to 1.0 and `categorical_crossentropy` adds some smoothing.

See the answer here for a discussion on logits: [What is the meaning of the word logits in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41455101/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-word-logits-in-tensorflow)

You can also use the sparse version of the function if each input value can only have one label:

```
print(sparse_categorical_crossentropy(16, y_pred))
```

Answer (score 2):

Found where the problem is

I used **softmax** activation in my last layer

`output = Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax')(x)`

But I used `from_logits=True` in `tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy`, which resulted in **softmax** being applied again on the output of the last layer (which was already `softmax(logits)`). So, the `output` argument that I was passing to the loss function was `softmax(softmax(logits))`.

Hence, the anomaly in the values of loss.

When using `softmax` as activation in the last layer, we should use `from_logits=False`