# Why is TensorFlow model reporting incorrect high confidence level for predictions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I wrote this function that takes in an image and generates a prediction. The level of confidence for the prediction that the function reports is greater than 100% many times. Sometimes the prediction is correct and reports a high level of confidence. Sometimes it is incorrect and still reports a high level of confidence. Can you please help me identify the error in my level of confidence code?

Final line of model structure:

```
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your output to be between 0 and 1, you should use either a `'sigmoid'` or `'softmax'` activation in your last layer:

```
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')(x)
```

Careful, however, because softmax output can't really be interpreted as probability.

Comment: Why can't softmax output be interpreted as probability?

Comment: Thank you Nicolas. What can I use to generate an accurate probability?

Comment: Softmax probabilities are uncalibrated but they are still probabilities.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Why are softmax probabilities uncalibrated? I don't think this is an inherent issue in all softmax regression e.g., multinomial logistic regression. (Binary logistic regression has good calibration.)

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by uncalibrated? How can I generate a calibrated probability?

Comment: @user17020095 That's really a question to as on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Read this paper about the topic: https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.04599

Comment: Thank you @Dave and @Dr. Snoopy! @Nicolas I see " UserWarning: "`sparse_categorical_crossentropy` received `from_logits=True`, but the `output` argument was produced by a sigmoid or softmax activation and thus does not represent logits. Was this intended?" What is the relationship between softmax and logits? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41455101/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-word-logits-in-tensorflow I see that logits help map probabilities.

Comment: You will indeed need to remove `from_logits=True`.